# Writing a conditional for printElements function that has 100+ Values

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I am making a currencey exchange application by making an API call to currencey exchange website. I want the option for the user to select any desired currencey from around the world. With a succsesful API call, a JSON is returned

```json
   {
    "result": "success",
    "documentation": "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
    "terms_of_use": "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms",
    "time_last_update_unix": 1673481602,
    "time_last_update_utc": "Thu, 12 Jan 2023 00:00:02 +0000",
    "time_next_update_unix": 1673568002,
    "time_next_update_utc": "Fri, 13 Jan 2023 00:00:02 +0000",
    "base_code": "USD",
    "conversion_rates": {
        "USD": 1,
        "AED": 3.6725,
        "AFN": 89.8016,
        "ALL": 109.0819,
        "AMD": 395.8582,
        "ANG": 1.7900,
        "AOA": 511.1933,
        "ARS": 180.3325,
        "AUD": 1.4481,
        "AWG": 1.7900,
        "AZN": 1.6989,
        "BAM": 1.8196,
        "BBD": 2.0000,
        "BDT": 103.8073,
        "BGN": 1.8196,
        "BHD": 0.3760,
        "BIF": 2067.3074,
        "BMD": 1.0000,
        "BND": 1.3312,
        "BOB": 6.9149,
        "BRL": 5.1987,
        "BSD": 1.0000,
        "BTN": 81.6573,
        "BWP": 12.7633,
        "BYN": 2.5109,
        "BZD": 2.0000,
        "CAD": 1.3418,
        "CDF": 2055.9987,
        "CHF": 0.9300,
        "CLP": 826.7277,
        "CNY": 6.7674,
        "COP": 4779.3841,
        "CRC": 585.8749,
        "CUP": 24.0000,
        "CVE": 102.5848,
        "CZK": 22.3444,
        "DJF": 177.7210,
        "DKK": 6.9408,
        "DOP": 56.5585,
        "DZD": 136.5304,
        "EGP": 28.4516,
        "ERN": 15.0000,
        "ETB": 53.5835,
        "EUR": 0.9304,
        "FJD": 2.1839,
        "FKP": 0.8235,
        "FOK": 6.9408,
        "GBP": 0.8235,
        "GEL": 2.6734,
        "GGP": 0.8235,
        "GHS": 10.4821,
        "GIP": 0.8235,
        "GMD": 63.0672,
        "GNF": 8653.3405,
        "GTQ": 7.8366,
        "GYD": 209.0327,
        "HKD": 7.8128,
        "HNL": 24.6584,
        "HRK": 7.0097,
        "HTG": 148.0084,
        "HUF": 370.9793,
        "IDR": 15436.3431,
        "ILS": 3.4421,
        "IMP": 0.8235,
        "INR": 81.6574,
        "IQD": 1459.6724,
        "IRR": 41971.2662,
        "ISK": 143.9749,
        "JEP": 0.8235,
        "JMD": 152.8483,
        "JOD": 0.7090,
        "JPY": 132.2611,
        "KES": 123.6722,
        "KGS": 85.4781,
        "KHR": 4119.4417,
        "KID": 1.4479,
        "KMF": 457.7013,
        "KRW": 1245.8448,
        "KWD": 0.3059,
        "KYD": 0.8333,
        "KZT": 461.9412,
        "LAK": 17033.9499,
        "LBP": 1507.5000,
        "LKR": 364.2070,
        "LRD": 154.3269,
        "LSL": 16.9409,
        "LYD": 4.7881,
        "MAD": 10.2148,
        "MDL": 19.1559,
        "MGA": 4543.5399,
        "MKD": 57.4550,
        "MMK": 2096.9659,
        "MNT": 3440.6855,
        "MOP": 8.0470,
        "MRU": 36.3695,
        "MUR": 43.9635,
        "MVR": 15.4304,
        "MWK": 1028.1896,
        "MXN": 18.9919,
        "MYR": 4.3712,
        "MZN": 64.0975,
        "NAD": 16.9409,
        "NGN": 449.9128,
        "NIO": 36.4912,
        "NOK": 9.9897,
        "NPR": 130.6517,
        "NZD": 1.5721,
        "OMR": 0.3845,
        "PAB": 1.0000,
        "PEN": 3.7946,
        "PGK": 3.5199,
        "PHP": 54.9816,
        "PKR": 228.4668,
        "PLN": 4.3584,
        "PYG": 7384.4414,
        "QAR": 3.6400,
        "RON": 4.5908,
        "RSD": 109.2836,
        "RUB": 69.1497,
        "RWF": 1085.6315,
        "SAR": 3.7500,
        "SBD": 8.3868,
        "SCR": 13.2984,
        "SDG": 538.0288,
        "SEK": 10.4712,
        "SGD": 1.3317,
        "SHP": 0.8235,
        "SLE": 19.5029,
        "SLL": 19502.8928,
        "SOS": 568.0050,
        "SRD": 32.0441,
        "SSP": 679.5885,
        "STN": 22.7935,
        "SYP": 2536.3858,
        "SZL": 16.9409,
        "THB": 33.4146,
        "TJS": 10.2240,
        "TMT": 3.4958,
        "TND": 3.0930,
        "TOP": 2.3699,
        "TRY": 18.7763,
        "TTD": 6.7711,
        "TVD": 1.4479,
        "TWD": 30.3627,
        "TZS": 2335.6703,
        "UAH": 36.7444,
        "UGX": 3687.5599,
        "UYU": 39.8317,
        "UZS": 11294.5364,
        "VES": 19.0531,
        "VND": 23436.0815,
        "VUV": 120.6118,
        "WST": 2.6811,
        "XAF": 610.2684,
        "XCD": 2.7000,
        "XDR": 0.7443,
        "XOF": 610.2684,
        "XPF": 111.0203,
        "YER": 250.0901,
        "ZAR": 16.9536,
        "ZMW": 18.3080,
        "ZWL": 704.5695
    }
}
```

I have a select input form on my HTML

```html
<form id="form">
      <label for="usdInput">US Dollars</label>
      <input id="usdInput" type="number" name="usdInput">
      <select id="selectCurrencey">
        <option value="USD"></option>
        <option value="AED"></option>
        <option value="AFN"></option>
        <option value="ALL"></option>
        <option value="AMD"></option>
        <option value="ANG"></option>
        <option value="AOA"></option>
        <option value="ARS"></option>
        <option value="AUD"></option>
        <option value="AWG"></option>
        <option value="AZN"></option>
        <option value="BAM"></option>
        <option value="BBD"></option>
        <option value="BDT"></option>
        <option value="BGN"></option>
        <option value="BHD"></option>
        <option value="BIF"></option>
        <option value="BMD"></option>
        <option value="BND"></option>
        <option value="BOB"></option>
        <option value="BRL"></option>
        <option value="BSD"></option>
        <option value="BTN"></option>
        <option value="BWP"></option>
        <option value="BYN"></option>
        <option value="BZD"></option>
        <option value="CAD"></option>
        <option value="CDF"></option>
        <option value="CHF"></option>
        <option value="CLP"></option>
        <option value="CNY"></option>
        <option value="COP"></option>
        <option value="CRC"></option>
        <option value="CUP"></option>
        <option value="CVE"></option>
        <option value="CZK"></option>
        <option value="DJF"></option>
        <option value="DKK"></option>
        <option value="DOP"></option>
        <option value="DZD"></option>
        <option value="EGP"></option>
        <option value="ERN"></option>
        <option value="ETB"></option>
        <option value="EUR"></option>
        <option value="FJD"></option>
        <option value="FKP"></option>
        <option value="FOK"></option>
        <option value="GBP"></option>
        <option value="GEL"></option>
        <option value="GGP"></option>
        <option value="GHS"></option>
        <option value="GIP"></option>
        <option value="GMD"></option>
        <option value="GNF"></option>
        <option value="GTQ"></option>
        <option value="GYD"></option>
        <option value="HKD"></option>
        <option value="HNL"></option>
        <option value="HRK"></option>
        <option value="HTG"></option>
        <option value="HUF"></option>
        <option value="IDR"></option>
        <option value="ILS"></option>
        <option value="IMP"></option>
        <option value="INR"></option>
        <option value="IQD"></option>
        <option value="IRR"></option>
        <option value="ISK"></option>
        <option value="JEP"></option>
        <option value="JMD"></option>
        <option value="JOD"></option>
        <option value="JPY"></option>
        <option value="KES"></option>
        <option value="KGS"></option>
        <option value="KHR"></option>
        <option value="KID"></option>
        <option value="KMF"></option>
        <option value="KRW"></option>
        <option value="KWD"></option>
        <option value="KYD"></option>
        <option value="KZT"></option>
        <option value="LAK"></option>
        <option value="LBP"></option>
        <option value="LKR"></option>
        <option value="LRD"></option>
        <option value="LSL"></option>
        <option value="LYD"></option>
        <option value="MAD"></option>
        <option value="MDL"></option>
        <option value="MGA"></option>
        <option value="MKD"></option>
        <option value="MMK"></option>
        <option value="MNT"></option>
        <option value="MOP"></option>
        <option value="MRU"></option>
        <option value="MUR"></option>
        <option value="MVR"></option>
        <option value="MWK"></option>
        <option value="MXN"></option>
        <option value="MYR"></option>
        <option value="MZN"></option>
        <option value="NAD"></option>
        <option value="NGN"></option>
        <option value="NIO"></option>
        <option value="NOK"></option>
        <option value="NPR"></option>
        <option value="NZD"></option>
        <option value="OMR"></option>
        <option value="PAB"></option>
        <option value="PEN"></option>
        <option value="PGK"></option>
        <option value="PHP"></option>
        <option value="PKR"></option>
        <option value="PLN"></option>
        <option value="PYG"></option>
        <option value="QAR"></option>
        <option value="RON"></option>
        <option value="RSD"></option>
        <option value="RUB"></option>
        <option value="RWF"></option>
        <option value="SAR"></option>
        <option value="SBD"></option>
        <option value="SCR"></option>
        <option value="SDG"></option>
        <option value="SEK"></option>
        <option value="SGD"></option>
        <option value="SHP"></option>
        <option value="SLE"></option>
        <option value="SLL"></option>
        <option value="SOS"></option>
        <option value="SRD"></option>
        <option value="SSP"></option>
        <option value="STN"></option>
        <option value="SYP"></option>
        <option value="SZL"></option>
        <option value="THB"></option>
        <option value="TJS"></option>
        <option value="TMT"></option>
        <option value="TND"></option>
        <option value="TOP"></option>
        <option value="TRY"></option>
        <option value="TTD"></option>
        <option value="TVD"></option>
        <option value="TWD"></option>
        <option value="TZS"></option>
        <option value="UAH"></option>
        <option value="UGX"></option>
        <option value="UYU"></option>
        <option value="UZS"></option>
        <option value="VES"></option>
        <option value="VND"></option>
        <option value="VUV"></option>
        <option value="WST"></option>
        <option value="XAF"></option>
        <option value="XCD"></option>
        <option value="XDR"></option>
        <option value="XOF"></option>
        <option value="XPF"></option>
        <option value="YER"></option>
        <option value="ZAR"></option>
        <option value="ZMW"></option>
        <option value="ZWL"></option>
        
        
        
        
      </select><br>
```

Then the printElements when API call is 200

```js
 function printElements(response, usd) {
  let currencySelect = document.getElementById('SELECTED OPTION').value
  document.getElementById('showExchange').innerText = `${usd} to ${response["conversion_rates"].'SELECTED OPTION'}`
}
```

Instead of writing 100+ if statements...
is there a way to select the input of which currencey is selected and check to see if that value is equal to currencey key in the JSON in order to print it to the DOM?

I have not tried writing the 100+ if statements, wondering if anyone else knew?

Comment: It's not clear what 100+ if statements you're talking about. Do you mean `if (currencySelect in response.conversion_rates)`?

Comment: Is `getElementById('SELECTED OPTION')` supposed to be `getElementById('selectCurrencey')`?

Comment: What you want is: `response.conversion_rates[currencySelect]`